# Operating system in Blade server/Rack server?

Tags: blade-server

I am trying to understand blade servers and rack servers, and how they work(and differ from desktop computers)

I found one link for [blade_server](https://buy.hpe.com/in/en/compute/integrity-server-blades/integrity-bl800c-server-blades/integrity-bl860c-server-blade/hpe-integrity-bl860c-i6-server-blade/p/1009969447) on hp's website.

In the specification section, there is mention of processor, memory and storage, but there is no mention of Operating System.

Don't server blades come with operating system(Linux/Windows etc) installed? Or do operating systems have be installed separately?

Comment: HP - like many other vendors - will certify and support their server hardware for a number of different operating systems. IIRC you could and maybe still can order certain pre-installed OS with your HP servers but in all enterprises I worked at we always deployed our own OS as those enterprises all had their own enterprise license/support agreements with Microsoft, VMWare, Red Hat etc and didn't purchase either a pre-installed OS nor a license in combination with  their server hardware.

Comment: Second: I.m pretty sure that also the HPE webshop does not have all options that your typical HP reseller can can offer and include/add to your orders. So not available online does not mean: does not exist. The order value of blade centers and the server to fill them with  will exceed an IT departments typical credit card limits and usually aren't ordered online in the webshop, but rather your It department requests a quote matching your particular needs and configuration, you negotiated enterprise discount gets applied  and then a purchase order or similar gets signed.

Comment: Yup. usually you have a TAM for your region or company and on special project, you contact them for a quote. after that on a bigger company you sign the paper for a forcast and purchase order and the buying department will order it on behalf the Requesters Quote.

Answer (score 2):

Servers with a price of "call for a quote" will have preinstalled operating system options, although you may need to talk to sales to find details.  Customers will demand support to get it working. The vendor will make setup ever so slightly faster, and ensure they stay in the support boundary, by having an operating system preinstalled.

The Integrity bl860c you found is a minority platform and does not have a future. Itanium is no longer sold. Linux and Windows were operating system options, but no longer. HP-UX is one of the very few operating systems that doesn't have a newer CPU platform option, which should tell you something about the lack of a future of that UNIX.  Likely its not that you pick your OS with such a server, its that you must buy Integrity line to run HP-UX.